# Scrape table from multiple pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape the data from [this](http://www.phdstipends.com/results) site.  The table extends onto multiple pages, however the url doesn't have something like `page=3`, so I can't loop over the various pages to get the data.

Is there another way I can scrape data like this without looping over various pages?  How can I access different pages from python in order to scrape the data?

Comment: Have a look at [**Selenium**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)

Comment: Where is your initial attempt that failed?

Comment: The data for this is pretty easily accessable through their JSON files. e.g. http://www.phdstipends.com/data/0, http://www.phdstipends.com/data/1, http://www.phdstipends.com/data/2

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge oh, that is interesting.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the direct JSON links given by @SeanBreckenridge, you could create a CSV file containing all the data as follows:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

header = ['University', 'Department', 'Overall Pay', 'LW Ratio', 'Academic Year', 'Program Year', 'Comment', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4']

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for index in range(30):
        url = 'http://www.phdstipends.com/data/{}'.format(index)
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)

        if len(r.text) < 20:
            break

        csv_output.writerows(json.loads(r.text)['data'])
```

Which would start:

```
University,Department,Overall Pay,LW Ratio,Academic Year,Program Year,Comment,V1,V2,V3,V4
University of California - Santa Barbara (UCSB),Chemical Engineering,"$31,125",1.27,2014-2015,1st,,"$31,250",,,$125
Pennsylvania State University (Penn State),Chemistry,"$20,500",1.11,2014-2015,2nd,,"$20,500",,,
University of California - San Diego (UCSD),Mathematics,"$20,500",0.87,2013-2014,4th,,,"$18,000","$2,500",
```